# how pass $index of ng-repeat to another ng-repeat in Angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I want show a json in 2 `select` in angularjs.

For this, I get below json from server:

`$scope.bolouks`:

```
{
  "dbId": 1,
  "boloukCode": "1-11-1",
  "north":  "...",
  "west":  "...",
  "radifs": [
    {
      "dbId": 1,
      "description": "...",
      "price": 698000
    },
    {
      "dbId": 2,
      "description":  "...",
      "price": 604000
    },
  ]
}
```

I want show first part of this json in a `select` and show `radifs` in other `select`.

For this, I try below code, but I'm not successful to manage second `select`:

```
<select ui-select2 name="bolouk" class="ui-select2" ng-model="br.bolouk" required ng-options="bolouk.dbId as bolouk.boloukCode for bolouk in bolouks">
   <option value=""></option>
 </select>
<select ui-select2 name="radif" class="ui-select2" ng-model="br.radif" ng-change="br.radif" required ng-options="radif.dbId as radif.description for radif in bolouks[br.bolouk].radifs">
  <option value=""></option>
</select>
```

I want use `$index` of `bolouks` in second select (`ng-repeat="radif in bolouks[$index].radifs"`), but it's not correct. How can I pass `index` of `bolouks` to second select?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only `ng-repeat` supports `$index`, not `ng-options`

The simplest way to cascade your selects is to simply set your ng-model as the selected "bolouk" and then have the second select run off the selected "bolouk's" "radifs".

```
<select ui-select2 name="bolouk" class="ui-select2" ng-model="br.bolouk" required ng-options="bolouk.boloukCode for bolouk in bolouks">
   <option value=""></option>
 </select>
<select ui-select2 name="radif" class="ui-select2" ng-model="br.radif" ng-change="br.radif" required ng-options="radif.dbId as radif.description for radif in br.bolouk.radifs">
  <option value=""></option>
</select>
```

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/reimavronicolas/8cjqy641/1/) showing something similar

Answer (score 0):

You should use chosen `Model` from the first select and use it in the second select.

For example:

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <select ng-model="firstChoise" ng-options="item as item.name for item in complexArray"></select>

    <select ng-model="secondChoise" ng-options="item for item in firstChoise.array"></select>
</div> 

function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.complexArray = [
        {name: "A", array: ["A1", "A2", "A3"]},
        {name: "B", array: ["B1", "B2", "B3"]},
        {name: "C", array: ["C1", "C2", "C3"]}
    ];
}
```

This is **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/shepard_one/HB7LU/9475/)** with working example.